# Contar meses que pasan entre 2 fechas a partir de 1 dia especifico

Tags: sql, server

Saluditos a todos trato de averiguar como capturar los meses que pasan entre 2 fechas dadas a partir de un dia especifico para generar 1 recargo incremental mensual, es decir
ejemplo: a partir de los 15 de cada mes se genere dicho recargo en primer mes 1% en segundo mes 2% y asi....
Lo intente con algunas funciones de sql server pero no consigo que sin importar el numero de días una vez pasado el día 15 del mes ya cuente como recargo antes no

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega lo que lleves al momento, checa [ask]

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: intente con datediff para calcular month pero me cuenta meses completos y en si lo que nesesito es que aunque no se cumplan los dias de 1 mes completo a partir de todos los 15 ya cuente como recargo de mes

Comment: Tendrias que editar la pregunta y agregar el codigo de lo que has intentado para que no te la reporten.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Usa el boton [edit] y agrega que intentaste asi no te proponemos algo que hayas intentado.. tambien agrega ejemplos de tus datos de entrada y como queres la salida, asi no tenemos que imaginar que queres...